selecting records based on sysdate not returning expected results
In the table the dates (ACTFINISH) are formatted as this 20190612000027
When I'm using this:
WHERE "ACTFINISH" >= SYSDATE-1;

It is returning all the records and not the expected selection.
Very new to SQL please be easy on me.

please specify DB you use. Most probably, it is Oracle. Please clarify the datatype of the column ACTFINISH. Is it DATE or something else

What are the latest dates in your table?

Execute select sysdate - 1 and see if it returns what you expect.

20190612000027 is an integer. SYSDATE is a datetime. Comparing the two will have strange effects.

The DB is Oracle.  The data type of 'ACTFINISH' is datetime.  The latest dates in the table are from today.
Tried sysdate -1 and still returned everything.
